# Scheme function that returns the index of the first location where an element occurs in the list

Tags: scheme

The last line of my code should returns the index of the first location where atm occurs in the list. for example (list-memeber? 9 '(4 9 3 6 8)) should return 2, but it gives me length + 1. Length + 1 should only work when atm doesn't occur in the list. How could I do that?

```
    (define (list-length l)
       (if (null? l)
         0
       (+ 1 (list-length (cdr l)))))

    (define (list-memeber? atm lst)
       (cond
       ((null? lst) '() ) ;returns null if list is empty (This part works fine)
       ((not (eq? atm (car lst))) (+ 1 (list-length lst))) ;If atm does not occur in the list, the function returns length + 1 ((This works fine)
       ((eq? atm (car lst)) 1) ;if fisrt element equals atm, function returns location which is 1 (This also works fine)
       (else (+ 1 (list-memeber? atm (cdr lst)))))) ;here is where I'm having problem. This should return location of index where atm occurs.
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are returning a number. I can see several problems. Eg. Imagine you don't find your element in a 3 element list.. It turns into:

```
(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 '()))) ; this part does not work fine!
```

I guess it should be `1` instead of `'()`. Further, if you in the current element don't find `atm`, which happens every time the desired element is not found in the very first element, you do `(+ 1 (list-length lst))` and effectively stop searching for it later in the structure.  Thus the general case `else` is never met since either it matches or it doesn't and a else after that would never be run.

To round it up fix `null?` case and remove the term with the predicate `(not (eq? atm (car lst)))` to get something working.